# ggplot2: How to bin continous values and assign specific colors to them

Tags: r, ggplot2

With `ggplot2` I want to bin continous values into three bins and assign a specific color to each of them.

In the following code example I want all values < 10 to be black, values >=10 and <= 100 to be red, and all values > 100 to be white.

```
data.frame(c = c("a", "b", "c"), v = c(1,50,500)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = c, x = "1", fill = v)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors = c("black", "red", "white"),
                    breaks = c(10, 100),
                    labels = c(10, 100))
```

But what I get is this:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Add `limits` around the `breaks`.

```r
data.frame(c = c("a", "b", "c"), v = c(1,50,500)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = c, x = "1", fill = v)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors = c("black", "red", "white"),
                    limits = c(9, 101), # NEW
                    breaks = c(10, 100))
```

[image]

This does not work as well with `limits=c(0,500)` or `limits=c(10,50)`, not sure exactly why tbh.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a good work around. Still don't understand what the function actually does.

Comment: It does seem strange as to why the limits are necessary and why they work. Is it at first assuming that `"white"` should be used to represent `500` and scaling the things accordingly? And therefore setting upper limit to 101 makes this the 'true' white value?

Comment: I agree fully, tbh, it seems like it's trying to infer something when the `colors=` and `breaks=` arguments should be clear enough. I've [commented](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5009#issuecomment-1889664536) on a related `ggplot2` issue, perhaps that'll spark some conversatwion?

Answer (score 0):

This does not use `scale_fill_stepsn`, but performs the intended plotting task (if I have understood the question correctly).

```
dat <- tibble(c = letters[1:5], v = c(1, 10, 50, 100, 500)) %>%
  mutate(vcat_color = case_when(
    v < 10 ~ "black",
    between(v, 10, 100) ~ "red",
    v > 100 ~ "white"
  ))

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = c, x = "1", fill = vcat_color)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_identity(
    "v", 
    breaks = c("black", "red", "white"), 
    labels = c("v < 10", "10 <= v >= 100", "v > 100"),
    guide = "legend"
    )
```